# Grok exporter show changes only after restart

Tags: grafana, prometheus, grok

We have configured Grok exporter to monitor errors from various system logs. But it seems changes are reflected once we restart the respective grok instance.

Please see the config.yml below:

```
global:
    config_version: 2
input:
    type: file
    path: /ZAMBAS/logs/Healthcheck/EFT/eftcl.log
    readall: true
    poll_interval_seconds: 5

grok:
    patterns_dir: ./patterns

metrics:
    - type: gauge
      name: EFTFileTransfers
      help: Counter metric example with labels.
      match: '%{WORD:Status}\s%{GREEDYDATA:FileTransferTime};\s\\%{WORD:Customer}\\%{WORD:OutboundSystem}\\%{GREEDYDATA:File};\s%{WORD:Operation};\s%{NUMBER:Code}'
      value: '{{.Code}}'
      cumulative: false
      labels:
          Customer: '{{.Customer}}'
          OutboundSystem: '{{.OutboundSystem}}'
          File: '{{.File}}'
          Status: '{{.Status}}'
          Operation: '{{.Operation}}'
          FileTransferTime: '{{.FileTransferTime}}'

    - type: gauge
      name: EFTFileSuccessfullTransfers
      help: Counter metric example with labels.
      match: 'Success\s%{GREEDYDATA:Time};\s\\%{WORD:Customer}\\%{WORD:OutboundSystem}\\%{GREEDYDATA:File};\s%{WORD:Operation};\s%{NUMBER:Code}'
      value: '{{.Code}}'
      cumulative: false

    - type: gauge
      name: EFTFileFailedTransfers
      help: Counter metric example with labels.
      match: 'Failed\s%{GREEDYDATA:Time};\s\\%{WORD:Customer}\\%{WORD:OutboundSystem}\\%{GREEDYDATA:File};\s%{WORD:Operation};\s%{NUMBER:Code}'
      value: '{{.Code}}'
      cumulative: false

server:
    port: 9845
```

Without restart it doesn't reflects correct matching patterns. Once I restart the grok instance it reflects perfectly.

Is there some parameter I am missing here ?

Thanks
Priyotosh

Answer (score 0):

Simply change `readall` to false in `input` section will stop process lines multiple times when grok_exporter is restarted. Please see the [docs](https://github.com/fstab/grok_exporter/blob/master/CONFIG.md#file-input-type) on Github.